# Why Dancer app fails under uWSGI + Apache?

Tags: apache, perl, uwsgi, dancer, psgi

My [Dancer](http://perldancer.org) app fails under uWSGI (2.0.7) + Apache (2.4.10) combination while it runs freely in other environments ( uWSGI + nginx, Starman + Apache, Dancer own dev-server). I don't find in logs any meaningful information. So I made simple test app like

```
$ dancer -a tset
```

Then copied default `production.yml` into `uwsgi.yml`, linked `bin/app.pl` into `bin/app.psgi` created `tset.ini` like this:

```
[uwsgi]                                                                                                                                                                             
plugins   = psgi                                                                                                                                                                    
socket    = 127.0.0.1:3033                                                                                                                                                          
uid       = www                                                                                                                                                                     
gid       = www-data                                                                                                                                                                
chdir     = /home/www/apps/tset/bin/                                                                                                                                                
psgi      = app.psgi                                                                                                                                                                
processes = 1                                                                                                                                                                       
master    = true
```

Made this ini available for uWsgi in `/etc/uwsgi/apps-available`, linked it into `/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled`.

Restarted `uwsgi` service.

Then for Apache (2.4.10) module `mod-proxy-uwsgi` added few lines into my virtualhost conf:

```
ProxyPass /adm/y uwsgi://127.0.0.1:3033/
```

This seems most fragile point, because I feel like I need to set `uWSGIModifier1 5` here but did not figured out where and how?

Restarted Apache and got "Internal Server Error". In uwsgi log I see just:

```
Tue Jan 19 02:10:36 2016 - spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 21712, cores: 1)
Tue Jan 19 02:10:56 2016 - -- unavailable modifier requested: 0 --
Tue Jan 19 02:24:44 2016 - -- unavailable modifier requested: 0 --
Tue Jan 19 02:27:14 2016 - -- unavailable modifier requested: 0 --
Tue Jan 19 02:27:17 2016 - -- unavailable modifier requested: 0 --
```

What is this "unavailable modifier requested"?

In apache error.log is no entries, in access.log are entries, but no other information than status 500.

Such behavior is reproducible with steps above, so I hope you figure out, what is wrong in this combination?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I feel like I need to set `uWSGIModifier1 5` here but did not figured out where and how?

Yes, you're right. You should set modifier1 to 5, but [uwsgi docs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Apache.html#mod-proxy-uwsgi) says about mod_proxy_uwsgi:

> Currently the module lacks the ability to set modifiers, though this will be fixed soon.

That means, you can't pass modifier to uWSGI instance using this method (uWSGI will use modifier 0 if not supplied)

To fix that issue, you can move to [mod_uwsgi](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Apache.html#mod-uwsgi) or change modifier on which psgi is loaded, using:

```
plugins   = 0:psgi
```

instead of

```
plugins   = psgi
```

Comment: Sorry for delay. This was good hint and after moving to the `0:psgi` I have a little progress. In uwsgi log is now `--- unable to find perl application ---` and another messy line `[pid: 5757|app: -1|req: -1/1] 212.7.22.161 () {66 vars in 1511 bytes} [Sat Jan 23 00:07:15 2016] GET /adm/z/ => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)` Here I see, that resonse is 21 bytes, what is length of "Internal server error".  Do you have any hints more, why Perl app is not found under Apache here?

Comment: Found out, that www-data usesr did not have same `@INC`, that's why Perl app was not found. So I got uwsgi run under Apache2 too. Thank you!